# Keycloak add custom attributes to user through confidential client

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I'm trying to add custom attributes to a user using the Java SDK but receive a **400 Bad Request**.
Here's my code:

```
UserResource userResource = usersResource.get(userId);
UserRepresentation user = userResource.toRepresentation();

Map<String, List<String>> attributes = user.getAttributes() != null
        ? user.getAttributes() : new HashMap<>();

attributes.put("attribute1", List.of("value1"));
attributes.put("attribute2", List.of("value2"));
attributes.put("attribute3", List.of("value3"));

user.setAttributes(attributes);

userResource.update(user);
```

Updating standard attributes like `first name` work though, is there some other Account Service Role I need than manage users, I think I've tried them all..

[image: Client configuration]

[image: Client scope]

[image: Client account service roles]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that one of the attribute values were too long.
Found it by reading the logs from Keycloak server.